# Central deployment of startup.py in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS 3 on Win10 we use a `startup.py` script for setting up e.g. database connections and a couple of other things, residing in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3`

What we are after is to centrally deploy the `startup.py` without having to distribute it to each of our clients at every script change.

First try was to make use of the `PYQGIS_STARTUP` environment variable, but this fails, because `startup.py` makes use of `qgis.*` modules which are of course not available before QGIS initialization is complete.

How can we centrally deploy our `startup.py` in order to apply changes on every client without having to distribute it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Our solution is to let the environment variable `PYQGIS_STARTUP` point to a very simple `pre-startup.py` script that copies the `startup.py` from a central location to the required users QGIS 3 directory:

```py
import os, shutil

account = os.getlogin()
shutil.copy2('X:/central/location/for/startup.py', 'C:/Users/{0}/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3'.format(account))
```

QGIS 3 then executes this previously copied `startup.py`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to startup.py, which is local, is the use of the `init_scripts` folder.

By default the init_scripts is set to `QgsApplication.pkgDataPath() + '/init_scripts'`.

All .py files inside that folder will run on qgis launching by alphabetic order.

You can use the QGIS_INIT_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY environment variable to point to another folder, including a path in a shared folder.

Comment: are you sure that this is already implemented in QGIS? I think it was only implemented in the boundlessgeo QGIS fork. I can't find QGIS_INIT_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY or init_scripts in the current codebase of QGIS. It would be nice if this functionality would be merged into the QGIS repository.

Comment: Yes, I presume that this feature is not available for a "regular" QGIS version. I create "Feature request": https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55714

Comment: It seems to me this answer doesn't apply to the official QGIS distribution.