# Check whether QGIS3 was started by qgis.bat or qgis.exe

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to check whether QGIS3 was started by executing **qgis.bat** or **qgis.exe** directly?

I want to do some checks in the qgis.bat before qgis starts and make sure that qgis is always started by calling the qgis.bat.

**Edit1**:

One idea is to set an environment variable in the qgis bat and check in the startup.py if this environmental variable is found:

bat-file:

```
set batchfilestart="YES"
```

python part

```
import os
try:  
    env_value = os.environ.get("batchfilestart")
    if env_value !="YES":
        print ("QGIS not started by calling the bat file")
        print (env_value)
    else:
        print("QGIS started by calling the bat file")
        print (env_value)
except KeyError: 
    print("Not exist environment value for %s" % "key_maybe_not_exist")
```

Is there a better way to make sure I can always run some checks before QGIS starts?

Comment: How about to add just a line with `pause` into qgis.bat? Then if you will see a message `Press any key to continue . . .` if you have launched the .bat file. Or rename qgis-bin.exe into foo.exe and edit the qgis.bat accordingly. At least for me foo.exe does not start at all but edited qgis.bat works. I was testing with the QSGeo4W installation.

Comment: @user30184: each user can pin qgis.exe to the taskbar or just run it manually. It's about rolling out QGIS for several persons where I want to make sure that all of them start QGIS3 only with the qgis.bat

Comment: Did you try renaming qgis-bin.exe into foo.exe? It seems that the renamed exe tries to find c:\osgeo4w\bin\foo.env which does not exist and `Oops, looks like an error loading QGIS` follows.

Comment: @user30184: renaming qgis-bin.exe or qgis-bin.env so they don't match anymore works to prevent calling qgis.exe directly but I am not sure if then really no neccessary settings get lost

Comment: If the reason for doing this is checking whether `startup.py` is current, why not have `startup.py` itself do that check, without relying on the `.bat` file?

Comment: @das-g: because the user could just delete the startup.py

Comment: Maybe you're aiming for something similar as https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319225/51574, then.