# Preset the setting of the QGIS option for all users

Tags: qgis

In our administration, QGIS should be made available to everyone.

Is there a possibility of the setting in the option e.g.
Settings / Options / General to remove the checkmark in the application "Show QGIS news on welcome page" for everyone in advance?
Or
Preset the reference system for everyone under Settings / Option / KBS?

The problem is that the settings are saved in the respective user profile and the basic setting is used when QGIS is started for the first time, i.e. without optimizing the options.
It is possible to start QGIS via a cmd.

If it is possible, it would be nice if someone could send me a template or a tip.
P.S. we are using QGIS 3.18

QGIS is provided on a Windows server for the entire administration. The call is made via a cmd. The options are saved in the user's profile. It would be nice if QGIS would access an option setting that was preset by me and not the default.

My question is similar to the following question:
Centralizing QGIS connections for multiple QGIS installations?

Comment: How to do this would probably depend on your operating system and how you deploy applications to your users

Comment: please use the [edit] link to improve your question

Comment: This could be a usefull read : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186624/deploying-qgis-settings-in-an-enterprise-environment and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319224/central-deployment-of-startup-py-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

Too many possibilities

**Option 1**: You can replace the content in QGIS3.ini file of your users. In your particular case, replace `NewsFeed\httpsfeedqgisorg\disabled=false` with `NewsFeed\httpsfeedqgisorg\disabled=true`

To find QGIS3.ini file, in a PyQGIS console, execute

```py
import os
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

print(os.path.join(QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath(), 'QGIS', 'QGIS3.ini'))
```

Drawback: you need QGIS already started once

**Option 2**:

To manipulate settings (and behind the scene, QGIS3.ini file), using `startup.py`, you can do for your particular option

```
settings = QSettings()
settings.setValue("core/NewsFeed/httpsfeedqgisorg/disabled", True)
```

The less intrusive IMHO: you adapt to existing e.g if first start and you patch on the fly the config but all config on existing install do not change

**Option 3**:

Start QGIS on one machine. Do your config. Then, you need to copy the profile folder you created on this particular machine to default path for QGIS profile on users machines `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\`. `<USER>` is the current user name you are connected with on your Windows session. You may need to replace some absolute paths in QGIS3.ini file before copying.

Useful in my opinion for first install of QGIS, not for existing QGIS install as you will overwrite existing users particular config (the profile folders contains not only GUI config but plugins, custom models, custom expressions, ...)

**Option 4**:

Dive into this recent project to prepare a custom installer to choose every options when you install QGIS https://github.com/haubourg/custom-osgeo4w-qgis

Caution: not intended for beginners but more for system administrators than end users

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Option 3 is a very good option for us. I created a profile and wanted to replace the standard profile with it. Unfortunately, I can't find a standard profile at all. The path: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\ does not exist at all. Do you have another tip?

Comment: USER is your own user. In my case, the user is `Thomas` so my path is `C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default` Open a command line (shortcut = Windows + R) and type `echo %username%` to get the real user name to replace USER. I've also edited my answer to be clearer (or I hope so)

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself a bit unclearly. I don't want to replace my profile, I want to save a profile that will be used for all users who start QGIS on the server for the first time.

Comment: I understood you to mean that, for example, I make all the desired settings in QGIS. Then close QGIS and. Then copy my profile and store it as a template for other users at a certain point that QGIS uses when it first starts. For this I have to save the profile in a place that QGIS uses as a standard when starting it for the first time. Can it be that the QGIS does not have an initial profile at all and only assembles it when it is started for the first time?